# Get URL from the database automatically

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm trying to automatically get a URL from my database table online when I click on the button `btnDelete`. The problem is that it returns the correct values from the database but when try to put it with:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(TAG_url);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

It says that *"unfortunately, access to database has stopped."*

When I make a `Log.d()` from the `TAG_url` it returns only "URL" but when I use

```
txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_url));
```

it displays correctly the link from the database.

```
03-14 11:50:18.169: E/Trace(5227): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-14 11:50:31.499: E/AndroidRuntime(5227): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 11:50:31.499: E/AndroidRuntime(5227): java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
03-14 11:50:31.499: E/AndroidRuntime(5227):     at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:464)
03-14 11:50:31.499: E/AndroidRuntime(5227):     at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:454)
03-14 11:50:31.499: E/AndroidRuntime(5227):     at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:426)
03-14 11:50:31.499: E/AndroidRuntime(5227):     at com.example.androidhive.EditProductActivity1$2.onClick(EditProductActivity1.java:106)
03-14 11:50:31.499: E/AndroidRuntime(5227):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-14 11:50:31.499: E/AndroidRuntime(5227):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
03-14 11:50:31.499: E/AndroidRuntime(5227):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-14 11:50:31.499: E/AndroidRuntime(5227):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-14 11:50:31.499: E/AndroidRuntime(5227):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-14 11:50:31.499: E/AndroidRuntime(5227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-14 11:50:31.499: E/AndroidRuntime(5227):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 11:50:31.499: E/AndroidRuntime(5227):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 11:50:31.499: E/AndroidRuntime(5227):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-14 11:50:31.499: E/AndroidRuntime(5227):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-14 11:50:31.499: E/AndroidRuntime(5227):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 11:50:44.299: E/Trace(5251): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Can anybody help me please?

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

    EditText txtName;
    EditText txtPrice;
    EditText txtDesc;
    EditText txtimg;
    EditText txtCreatedAt;
    Button btnSave;
    Button btnDelete;
    Button btnvideo;

    String pid;
    String url;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single product url
    private static final String url_product_detials = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

    // url to update product
    private static final String url_update_product = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/update_product.php";

    // url to delete product
    private static final String url_delete_product = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/delete_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String TAG_img = "img";
    private static final String TAG_url = "url";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);

        // save button
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        // getting product details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting product id (pid) from intent
        pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

        // Getting complete product details in background thread
        new GetProductDetails().execute();

        // save button click event
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // starting background task to update product
                new SaveProductDetails().execute();
            }
        });

        // Delete button click event
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // deleting product in background thread
                Log.v(TAG_url, "index=");
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(TAG_url);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    /**
    * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
    * */
    class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
        * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
        * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading movies details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
        * Getting product details in background thread
        * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this pid found
                            // Edit Text
                            url = TAG_url;
                            Log.v(url, "index=");
                            txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                            txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                            txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);
                            // txtimg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputimg);

                            // display product data in EditText
                            txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                            txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                            txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_url));
                            txtimg.setText(product.getString(TAG_img));
                        } else {
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                private String getText(String string) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        /**
        * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
        * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
    * Background Async Task to Save product Details
    * */
    class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
        * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
        * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
        * Saving product
        * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // getting updated data from EditTexts
            String name = txtName.getText().toString();
            String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();
            String img = txtimg.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_img, img));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_url, url));

            // sending modified data through http request
            // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check json success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully updated
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to update product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
        * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
        * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that the var `TAG_url` is intended to be used only as a descriptor, not as a mutable object.  First you have: `private static final String TAG_url = "url";` defined as a node name.  Using that for `txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_url));` works because you're retrieving the data associated with the node "url" (which is what `TAG_url` holds).  In that instance, the data is not in the `TAG_url` var, but uses `TAG_url` as the key to find the data.

Any log reference to `TAG_url` will return it's contents: `url`.  By the same token, a parse call using `TAG_url` will use it's contents as well.  Therefore, `Uri uri = Uri.parse(TAG_url);` is actually calling `Uri uri = Uri.parse("url");` - and so the error.

You should replace the `TAG_url` in the parse call with a var holding the actual url you intend to call.  During your database call, you should store that url in a separate var, and parse it instead.

Edit:

Without knowing the structure of your JSON or other data, I can't say for certain.  But as example, lets assume that the data returned from the database via the call `product.getString(TAG_url)` is the data you want sent to the parser.  (I'm assuming that since you mentioned the data was correctly set to the TextView `txtDesc` when called via `txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_url));`.)

Given that, you could create a field `String incomingURL;` at the top of the class, and assign the result of the database call like `incomingURL = product.getString(TAG_url);`.  You would then set the TextView with the new field like `txtDesc.setText(incomingURL);`.

Then, use that variable for your parse: `Uri uri = Uri.parse(incomingURL);`  That would take the data from the database call, and place it in the parser.  Just keep in mind that you'll need to check for `incomingURL` being null if the button is clickable before the database call completes.

Comment: Can you please give me a help on storing the actual url in a separate var? i had tried several times in diferent ways it seems im doing something wrong that i cant go further on it and it returns allways the url :/ i would really apriciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Comment added to answer - too long for comment box!  :)